# Can I use fine-thread drywall screws with wood framing?

Tags: drywall, wood, ceiling, screws, support

Is it okay to use fine thread drywall screws when securing drywall to wood studs? What’s the worst that could happen if not?

Comment: "Fine thread" DW screws are intended for fastening drywall to sheet metal studs rather than wood ones.  In general they should work for wood studs but there is a modest danger of the screws stripping out the holes and coming loose.

Answer (score 7):

It's fine. They are primarily intended for metal studs but they will work fine in wood. Think about the force required to physically pull out one screw - even a fine threaded screw. Now given the fact that each sheet of drywall will typically have about 32 screws, the drywall itself will fail long before the screw is pulled out. To make yourself feel better, drive a fine threaded screw 3/4 of its length into a stud. Then grab pliers and try to pull it out...

Answer (score 2):

Should be fine, though each screw will take longer to drive than with a coarser thread.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use fine thread. Use the coarse thread screws. Over time wood expands and contracts with heat and humidity. Combine that with the weight of the drywall they WILL pop eventually. The question is will you still be there to fix all the popped screws? There are different threads for a reason if your going to spend the time doing something do it right the first time.

Comment: I mean they used to use nails tho

Comment: True there are a lot of things we "used to do" but found better ways. I remodeled many an old house and have seen those nails (popped out).

Comment: Nah. I've demolished enough framing to know that fine-thread screws hold just fine. Screw pops occur due to missing the framing and gaps behind the drywall, not because of thread type.